# How to communicate between iOS and Android Device Apps by Wifi?

Tags: android, ios, android-tv

I want to communicate between iOS and Android OS. The core concept is.

**1. I have an app, made for Android TV Box. This App downloads data from server and show on Android TV Box.**

**2. I want to control it through iOS and Android Phones. I want this app to be a Keyboard and MOUSE for ONLY my Android TV Box App.**

Concepts in my mind.

**1. I think, I have to use WIFI, which could connect both apps, Android TV Box and Android App, and I pass characters and Positions via Android and which will be received by Android TV Box app and further process it.**

**2. I made Android TV Box App, a server host, and connect both to that IP, and process.**

I research, here and there, and I found "AllJoyn"

https://allseenalliance.org

I read this a bit, while I thought to post Question on Stack to get better guidance.

Comment: You need a server app on the tv box. And client apps on ios and android devices.

Comment: `2. I make Android TV Box, a local host, `. That is nonsense. You probably mean that you will run a server app on the box.

Comment: @greenapps, Now check. It is to communicate both with a help of server, but thats also nonsense, as I want P2P. So it gonna end its essence.

Comment: @greenapps, I want to sent data from iOS and Android App to Android TV Box App, which will process data which it got from devices. Its like a REMOTE for Android TV Box App.

Comment: Why are you repeating yourself? It's very clear what you want.

Comment: `and connect both to that IP`. Both? Which ip? Only a client has to connect. A client should use the ip of the device where the server is running on.

Comment: @greenapps, So, if you have answer, answer it, else if you have query, let me know.

Comment: Well i answered already. Something unclear? Feel free to ask.

Comment: @greenapps, I think we both confusing it. I simply want to pass data, so, what should I do.

Comment: Let the client send data (characters and mouse positions) to the server. The server receives the data and handles it.

Comment: Server, where to establish server, on a hosting or inside TV Box App?

Comment: Inside tv box app. I will not chat.

Comment: okay, so you want me to make a server, inside tv box app and which will receive data from ios and android app, this is what we conclude here. @greenapps,

Comment: Indeed. It's as simple as that. Google for client/server example code. You only need very simple code. Well for the sending and receiving part.

Comment: Yes, but what about iOS :) I have to sent data from iOS app also to Android TV Box server @greenapps

Comment: The same. Make a client app for ios. I already told that.

Comment: Okay. I start more search and check google demo. Thanks @greenapps